# Mule - java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

I'm using a data mapper which maps xml file to array of maps. While logging I get the result given below:

```
[{Name=xyz, Salary=30000, Tax=1000}, {Name=BOS, Salary=200, Tax=75}]
```

From the above resulting map I'm trying to insert value to the database based on where clause. My query looks something like this:

```
UPDATE employee SET Salary =#[message.payload[0]['Salary']]  WHERE name = #[message.payload[0]['Name']]
```

Here I'm getting exception which looks something like:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List
at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.ListAccessor.getValue(ListAccessor.java:40)
at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.GetterAccessor.getValue(GetterAccessor.java:40)
at org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.VariableAccessor.getValue(VariableAccessor.java:37)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

While logging using  **#[message.payload[0]['Salary']]** I get the value associated with it correctly. But the same expression in query doesn't work for me.

Waiting for your reply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take the first item (or split the array) before using the query:

```
<set-payload value="#[payload[0]]" />
```

And then use just the map payload in the query:

```
#[message.payload['Salary']]
```

Comment: Well that's okay, but I'm still confused, why  #[message.payload[0]['Salary']]  doesn't work. In logger it's give me the correct value for the key "Salary".